# batch file xcopy to a partially unknown directory with a dot ( . ) in

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

Im trying to create a batch file that will copy a directory to another directory however, the directory I wish to copy too has a portion of the name randomly generated i.e. "jibberish.Directory1".
is there a way to do this ?

I was trying something like:

```
XCOPY "%~dp0DATA\test" "%APPDATA%\Application1\Directory\*Directory1\" /E /C /R /I /K /Y
```

but total fail. Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: What is the criterium for chosing that destination folder? If you use wildcards there might be more than one match. Should it be the most recently created, or most recently used, or...?

Comment: a process creates 100 folders, the folder naming structure is NAME.ID  . the ID is easy, 1 through to 100 for all 100 folders but the name varies. I need to add a directory (containing settings) to all the NAME.ID folders however dont want to have to copy names but can copy the line into excel or something and replicate with all 100 ascending numbers.. hope this helps explain a bit better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**xcopy** does not support wildcards in directory names. Therefore a **for** loop is additionally necessary for this task which is as follows:

In folder `C:\Temp` there is the batch file `DuplicateFolder.bat` with the code below.

The folder to duplicate is `DATA\test` in directory of the batch file.

`C:\Temp\DATA\test` contains:

- **SubFolder1**

  - FirstFile.txt
  - Second File.txt
- **Sub Folder 2**

  - ListFile.csv
- Readme.txt

All these subfolders and files should be copied to each subfolder in `%APPDATA%\Application1\Directory` ending with a number after a dot.

`%APPDATA%\Application1\Directory` contains for example:

- **Folder abc.1**
- **Folder e-g.2**
- **Folder h to k.3**
- **Folder last.4**
- **Folder not changed**

The last folder should be ignored as it does not contain a dot and a number at end.

The result should be for example for the first subfolder `Folder abc.1`:

- **Folder abc.1**

  - **SubFolder1**

    - FirstFile.txt
    - Second File.txt
  - **Sub Folder 2**

    - ListFile.csv
  - Readme.txt

Code of `DuplicateFolder.bat` is:

```
@echo off
set "SourceFolder=%~dp0DATA\test"
for /D %%F in ("%APPDATA%\Application1\Directory\*") do (
    if not "%%~xF" == "" %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%SourceFolder%" "%%~F" /E /C /Q /R /I /K /Y >nul
)
set "SourceFolder="
```

This batch file just checks if folder name contains a dot without checking if string after dot - the "file extension" referenced with `%%~xF` - is really a number. This very simple test is very fast.

For details about used command **for** and an explanation of the parameters and special loop variable references open a command prompt window, execute `for /?`, and read help output for this command in the console window.

Comment: You Sir, are a hero! This worked perfectly, I was unaware that you couldn't use wildcards with xcopy in the way i was attempting and hadn't looked at FOR. You truly have expanded my knowledge and saved me many hours of failure barking up the wrong tree. Thank you for taking the time out of your day to help with this, I really appreciate it ^_^